# How to find files with many duplicates in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In my project, there are lots of files with the same name like `index.html`. When I search with <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+R</kbd>, I find lots of files.

I want to search like `person/index.html`. Is there such a plug-in for Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter `*person/index.html` in the *Open Resource* dialog, you will only get the `index.html` in the `person` folder. Isn't that what you are looking for?